# Find parallel line numbers in a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Suppose I have a graph formed by 3 vertices and 4 lines.
`{4 <-> 1, 1 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 1 <-> 3}`
Let the line numbers be `{1,2,3,4}`. Now lines `2&4` are parallel lines.

Suppose I have a graph with `5000` vertices and `5500` lines.Assuming there are `300` parallel lines in the graph,how would you identify them along with line numbers?
In other words, how would you identify such parallel lines and its corresponding line numbers in a big graph?

Comment: Could you clarify how you define parallel in this context?

Comment: @MarcoB "Parallel edges" typically refers to edges connecting the same vertices.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do?  IGraph/M has several tools that help in dealing with multigraphs.  E.g., `IGWeightedSimpeGraph` will merge parallel edges *and sum their weights*.

Comment: @Szabolcs thank you for the clarification. I wasn’t aware of that.

Comment: @Szabolcs If I assign line numbers to every line, and form a graph and that graph has parallel lines, I want to get only the numbers of parallel lines

Answer (score 2):

You can identify the indices of parallel edges using

```
GroupBy[
  Thread[
    Range@EdgeCount[g] -> (Sort /@ EdgeList[g])
  ],
  Last -> First
]


(* <|1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4 -> {1}, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3 -> {2, 4}, 3 \ [UndirectedEdge] 4 -> {3}|> *)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
edges = {4 <-> 1, 1 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 1} ;
Select[Length @ # >= 2 &] @ GatherBy[Range @ Length @ edges, Sort @ edges[[#]]&]
```

> {{2, 4}}

Also

```
Select[Length @ # >= 2 &] @ Values @ 
  GroupBy[edges, (Sort @ # &) -> (Flatten[Position[edges, #]]&), First[#]&]

ac = ArrayComponents[Sort /@ edges];
Select[Length@# >= 2 &]@ Values@GroupBy[Range@Length@edges, ac[[#]] &]
```

both give

> {{2, 4}}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on `Tally` for obtaining the edges that have parallels:

```
edgeRules = {4 <-> 1, 1 <-> 3, 4 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1, 4 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4};
g = Graph[edgeRules];

parallelEdges = 
 First /@ Select[Tally[Sort /@ EdgeList[g]], Last[#] > 1 &]

(*  {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4}  *)
```

That is simple enough, but it gets a little more complicated if we want the position of the edges in the original `edgeRules`.  We could do something like this:

```
lineNumbers = Flatten[Union[Position[edgeRules, #],
     Position[edgeRules, Reverse[#]]]] & /@
  TwoWayRule @@@ parallelEdges    

(*  {{2, 4}, {3, 5, 6}}  *)
```

And retrieve the original rules that generated the parallel edges like this:

```
parallelRules = Part[edgeRules, #] & /@ lineNumbers

{{1 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, {4 <-> 3, 4 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4}}
```